devboxdefinitions cannot be created in the westeurope region at this time, because the resource quota has been exceeded in that region
I am trying to create a dev box with student subscription (I have ~190 Euros remaining), but it doesn't seem to work.
I am attaching photo of current usage, and it looks like I have 80% more (even tho i am not sure what that 20% is responsive for)

I viewed a videos of how to resolve that issue but I can't even request a quota increase (also attached)
Have anyone experienced this before?

I tried to resolve this issue by watching videos from other people, but increase quote button simply doesn't work.. Maybe that is because I am on student subsc


I tried to resolve this issue by watching videos from other people, but increase quote button simply doesn't work.. Maybe that is because I am on student subsc

According to this MS-Q&A by vipullag-MSFT.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to increase the quota for azure dev box on a student subscription.
The student subscription has a limited quota for certain resources, including vCPUs and memory.

If your student subscription doesn't provide enough resources, consider switching to a pay-as-you-go plan or buy Azure credits. This will give you access to more resources and higher quotas.
After Upgrading to pay-as-you-go or azure credits, you can able to see the button of New Quota Request.

Reference:
Request a quota limit increase for Dev Box resources - Microsoft Dev Box | Microsoft Learn
